# Where exactly is "Search settings" under "Settings"?

Tags: google-search

I want to turn off Google suggestions that came on apparently by itself after I used YouTube. So I'm instructed to go to "Settings", and choose "Search Settings"; however, I can't locate it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where a pictures says more than the words, I think

[image]

Anyway, using a desktop web browser

1. Go to https://www.google.com
2. Click on **Settings**
3. The emerging menu will show the Search Settings menu option